# I can't seem to run playn-showcase-android in eclipse

Tags: sample, playn

I'm currently trying to set up playn on eclipse to make a game on android I followed the installation steps here: http://0-code.google.com.precise.petronas.com.my/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted

I installed the Android development stuff and the Maven natives plugin and I even did all the android specific steps including adding a Maven installation that is compatible with the Android Maven plugin (in my case it was Maven 3.0.4).

I imported the sample files and tried to run the playn showcase for android and this is what I got:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PlayN Showcase Android 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/playn-showcase-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/playn-showcase-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/playn-showcase-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/playn/playn-showcase-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/playn-showcase-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.687s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 12 00:05:36 PDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project playn-showcase-android: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-android:apk:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in forplay-legacy (http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

So apparently I'm missing a POM for com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem with the regular Java version, and I followed the steps exactly.

Comment: BTW, this only happens from eclipse to me. From command line I can run just fine by going to playn-samples/showcase folder and doing mvn3 -Phtml integration-test

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Maven command from the top directory of your project instead of some sub-directory.
Read this somewhere. Maven seems to be stupid. For me it made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After writing the last comment on your question I figured out the solution:

- Right click on playn-showcase: **Run As -> Maven Build...**
- On the Edit Configuration window set:

  - Goals: Integration Test
  - Profiles: android

I was having a problem to build html but the error I got was the same, so in my case the solution was setting *html* under Profiles.